get the exception context address from a crashed process using its handle
we are able to launch a dump collection tool for jni crashes using jvm option -XX:OnError.
But like we get a jit address passed to the jit debugger in win32 app crashes we dont get it from jvm.
Is there an api to get the crash exceptio n context address from the process handle?

I'm not sure I understand the issue. Are you writing a custom tool to collect a minidump but the -XX:OnError option only provides you with the PID of the faulting application?

Pass GetCurrentProcess() and GetCurrentProcessId() to the values of hProcess and ProcessId of MiniDumpWriteDump. And I suggest to use Procdump by Microsoft. It's swift and simple.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump

@IInspectable, Correct. I want to know if there is a way to get the exception context from outside the process using its handle

I don't know of a way to do that, though you could try to use the debugging API. DebugActiveProcess() can attach to a running process and wait for debug events. I don't know if the exception event gets re-raised on attach (which would get you all the information you need).
